# Dynamic templateUrl while resolving in angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So right now I have a parent directive for an entire view so I can swap out templates based on the return status of a promise.

```
.directive('myDirective', function(myService) {
    var rootDir = '/path/to/templates';

    return {
         restrict: 'E',
         replace: true,
         controller: controller,
         link: linker,
         template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>'
    };

    function controller($scope) { ... }

    function linker(scope) { 
        myService.getData().then(function(res) {
            scope.getContentUrl = function() {
                var tpl = res.status >= 400 ? '/tplContent.html' : '/tplError.html';
                return rootDir + tpl; 
            };
        });    
    }
})
```

However, this would be much cleaner if I could call `myService.getData()` while resolving my angular-ui route and dynamically load the `templateUrl` after my promise resolves.

Answer (score 1):

What if you assign the results of `getData()` to the scope, and bind to that?

```
template: '<div ng-include="{{contentUrl}}"></div>'
```

---

```
function linker(scope) { 
    myService.getData().then(function(res) {
        var getContentUrl = function() {
            var tpl = res.status >= 400 ? '/tplContent.html' : '/tplError.html';
            return rootDir + tpl; 
        };

        $scope.contentUrl = getContentUrl();
    });    
}
```